# Inserting in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, tree

I'm inserting in BST in following way :

```
private void BSTinsert(int toInsert){
        if(root==null){
            root = new Node(toInsert);
            return;
        }
        Node tempRoot = root;
        while(tempRoot!=null){
            if(tempRoot.data > toInsert){
                tempRoot = tempRoot.left;
            }else{
                tempRoot = tempRoot.right;
            }
        }
        tempRoot = new Node(toInsert);
}
```

But when I try to print the tree from root, it throws a Null Pointer Exception. But when I try to print out tempRoot while inserting it prints out correctly, but arent root and tempRoot the same thing since I've equated them? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

`tempRoot` is a local variable, so when you assign the new Node to it, nothing in the existing tree is referring to it. The new Node should be linked to its parent (via the `left` or `right` references).

Currently your code only inserts the first Node correctly, since that Node becomes the root.

A suggested correction (not tested) :

```
private void BSTinsert(int toInsert){
    if(root==null){
        root = new Node(toInsert);
        return;
    }
    Node tempRoot = root;
    while(tempRoot!=null){
        if(tempRoot.data > toInsert){
            if (tempRoot.left == null) {
                tempRoot.left = new Node(toInsert);
                return;
            } else {
                tempRoot = tempRoot.left;
            }
        }else{
            if (tempRoot.right == null) {
                tempRoot.right = new Node(toInsert);
                return;
            } else {
                tempRoot = tempRoot.right;
            }
        }
    }
}
```